# 2006 Jeep Commander Driver's side window controls only work for rear windows

Tags: electrical, jeep, switches

My 2006 Jeep Commander driver side power window controls will only work for the rear windows. I have checked the switches and they are in working order. The front windows and the power mirror controls do not work I'm assuming there is a problem with the wiring harness. Please advise with repair procedures. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are the switches mounted on the door itself? Assuming all the fuses are in order, the most likely suspect is the 'snake' that takes the wires between the door and the car itself.

As you open and close the door, these wires have to flex, and can fatigue or break, or rub on the metalwork of the door and wear (although there should be a plastic harness or rubber grommet to stop that from happening). It's worth checking the condition of this.